# UX for uploading documents in long form flow

Tags: forms, business-application, flow

I have a government client using Pega to control the flow of a business case where a user flows through multiple form screens. Within several of these forms, the user is prompted to optionally upload supporting documents - optional but desired by the business for data gathering. There is disagreement about whether the user should be prompted to upload all documents at the end of the flow from a single view, or add the upload prompt to each screen where the context is provided. I am interested to hear if anyone has opinion on these options.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, that is the tricky case, let me offer what I think:

1. First of all, it's good to let people know about what documents are needed upfront, possibly at the form instructions - when they fill the form they don't want to start running around
2. I would advocate for adding docs on the page they are related to. At the time they reach the end you can expect a user to have form-fatigue :)
3. At the form review page I would add the opportunity to add missed docs once again. It's a nice moment the main job is already done but there is a moment to pause and think. It seems to be a good place to give extra chance

Good Luck!